# Chained Payment like functional for credit card checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I know about PayPal Chained Payments. They involve a primary (the goods seller) and secondary (the store) receipt and the primary one have full control over refunds and so on.

I want to have a way to process credit cards, without the buyer to have an PayPal account. I wonder if there is some mechanism to have a primary and secondary receipt in this case. How to handle fee receiving in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with the same sort of issue.

My research concluded that this cannot be done, with the current adaptive payments APIs.

So there are two solutions

1) Wait till the rest api team adds spilt payments to the rest APIs. You can follow development of this feature @ https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/9

2) Pay into one account (A nominee account look it up) and use mass payments to pay out to other accounts

Comment: Yeah, I've already implemented your second solution (with mass payment) but I don't like it because it doesn't give control over the refunds to the sellers.

Do you know some workaround for this?

Comment: We are personally dealing with this issue ourselves, so its ongoing for us aswell. 

You could try and hold the money (up to 90 days on paypal) If there is a refund then the nominee account issues that refund and you dont pay out to the other accounts.